# Put a checkbox in each table cell

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I'm trying to add checkboxes to each cell in my table.

If `$columns['mything$record']` is equal to 1, I want a checkbox that's checked to show up.

If `$columns['mything$record']` is equal to 0, I want a blank checkbox to show up. I've created if statements which one can view below, but they don't put a checkbox in each table cell with the respective value, only one blank checkbox appears at the top of the page.

How can I put checkboxes in each cell that are checked and unchecked based on the cell value?

[![screenshot][1]][1]

```
        $stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT record,shortName FROM dms 
            where dms.isInactive=0 
            ORDER BY lastName asc, firstName asc");
        $stmt->execute();

        $shortNameArray=array();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        //  print_r($row);
            $shortNameArray[$row['record']]=$row['shortName'];
        }
        //print_r($shortNameArray);

$columns = array(
    1 => array(
        "selectFieldName"       => "nrs.record nrRecord",
        "resultFieldName"       => "nrRecord",
        "headerName"            => "NT#",
        "defaultSortOrder"  => -1,
    ),
        array(
        "selectFieldName"       => "nrs.title",
        "resultFieldName"       => "title",
        "headerName"            => "Title",
        "defaultSortOrder"  => 1,
    ),  

);
$selectedColumnNumbers = array(1,2,3);
$counter=4;


foreach($shortNameArray as $record=>$name){


    if($record>0){
    $columns[]=array(


        "selectFieldName"       => "CASE WHEN $record IN (GROUP_CONCAT(dm_nr_links.dmRecord)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END mything$record",
        "resultFieldName"       => "mything$record",
        "headerName"            => "$name",
        "defaultSortOrder"  => 1,

        );


        $selectedColumnNumbers[]=$counter;
        $counter++;

        if ($columns['mything$record'] == 1) {

            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='PLJan' checked='checked' />";
            } 


        if ($columns['mything$record'] == 0) {



            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='JLFeb' />";



        }
    }
}



$selectedColumns = array();

$selectedFields = array(); // contains all the fields to be selected

foreach ($selectedColumnNumbers as $columnNumber){
    $selectedColumns[$columnNumber] = $columns[$columnNumber];
    if (strlen($columns[$columnNumber]["selectFieldName"]) > 0)
        $selectedFields[] = $columns[$columnNumber]["selectFieldName"];
}

    $selectedFields = array_unique($selectedFields); // Remove all      duplicate fields for selection

///// Process Filter Cookies
$filterWhereString = "";
$filterBindValues = array();
for ($c=1; $c<=5; $c++) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE["nrsfl$c"])
        && isset($_COOKIE["nrsfl$c"."Op"])
        && isset($_COOKIE["nrsfl$c"."Val"])
        && strlen($_COOKIE["nrsfl$c"."Val"]) > 0
    ) {
        $columnNumber = $_COOKIE["nrsfl$c"];
        $filterOperator = $_COOKIE["nrsfl$c"."Op"];
        $filterValue = $_COOKIE["nrsfl$c"."Val"];
        if (isset($columns[$columnNumber])){
            if ($c >= 2) {
                $lastC = ($c-1);
                if (strlen($filterWhereString) > 0) // If string exists, add conjunction
                {
                    if (isset($_COOKIE["nrsfl$lastC"."C"])){
                        $conSelect = $_COOKIE["nrsfl$lastC"."C"];
                    } else $conSelect = 1;
                    if ($conSelect == 1) $conjunction = "AND";
                        else $conjunction = "OR";
                    $filterWhereString .= "$conjunction ";
                }
            }
            $column = $columns[$columnNumber];
            $fieldName = $column['resultFieldName'];
            $filterWhereString .= "$fieldName ";
            switch ($filterOperator) {
                case 1:
                    $operator = "=";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $operator = "LIKE";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $operator = ">=";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $operator = "<=";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $operator = ">";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $operator = "<";
                    break;
                    case 8:
                    $operator = "NOT LIKE";
                    break;
                default:
                    $operator = "!=";
            }
            if ((strcmp($operator, "NOT LIKE") == 0) ||(strcmp($operator, "LIKE") == 0)) $filterField = "CONCAT('%',:filter".$c.",'%')";
            else $filterField = ":filter$c";
            $filterWhereString .= "$operator $filterField ";
            if (substr_compare($fieldName, "date", 0, 4) == 0) {    // Convert dates
                $filterValue = strtotime($filterValue);
                $filterValue = date("Y-m-d",$filterValue);
            }
                            if ($fieldName=="isRestricted") {   // Convert binaries
                if(strtolower($filterValue)=='y')$filterValue="1";
                if(strtolower($filterValue)=='n')$filterValue="0";
            }
            $filterBindValues[":filter$c"] = $filterValue;
        }
    }
}
/////
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code line

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='PLJan' ";
    echo  "checked='checked'";
```

with

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='PLJan' checked='checked' />";
```

---

### and

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='JLFeb' ";
```

with

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='JLFeb' />";
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work! Instead of one blank checkbox appearing at the top of the page, there are numerous. They're not in the table cells. Thank you though.

Comment: @JT222 i guess this is not the full code please show the part where you have printed the table.